# Does frightened cat drink a lot of water?

Tags: cats, psychology, fear, biology, drinking

Today, one of our tenants was on the rooftop. She had her huge teddy bear in hand.

At the same time, I went to roof to have a walk with Bhutu (my cat). By seeing the teddy, Bhutu was frightened to hell. She ran for her dear life into our rooms. Then, she started drinking water insanely.

Is it possible that when cats get frightened, they tend to drink a lot of water?

If so, I want to know the biochemical reactions that go inside the cat's body and resultant behavioral output.

Also, then my cat has gone to deep sleep by my side and is snoring.

Answer (score 4):

Just like humans, animals can have their own personal reactions to stress.

Just a simple example, we adopted two sisters who are prone to anxiety when strangers are nearby. One is a stress eater, the other is a stress faster.

It's possible that your cat drinks when stressed. It's also possible that she e.g. assumed the teddy bear was going to come in and claim everything for himself so she finished off what she could. We can't really know what goes on in your cat's mind. As far as I'm aware, water drinking is not a known universal feline response to stress.

**Update** There may be an indirect connection in that the scary event caused her to run very fast, which then caused her to need to drink afterwards.

Comment: What is your source to say that drinking water is not general feline response to stress.

Comment: @Sonevol: There is an absence of discussions on the topic. I can't conclusively prove a negative. At best, I can point out the absence of mentioning stress on [articles discussing cats drinking a lot of water](http://www.pethealthnetwork.com/cat-health/cat-diseases-conditions-a-z/why-my-cat-drinking-so-much). However, have you considered that it may be an indirect connection; and that she's not drinking from stress but rather because she ran very fast?

Comment: Do you think it may be related to the common phrase we have, "his throat has gone dry out of fear"?

Comment: @Sonevol: Not a common saying here, also not common in English as far as I'm aware, and again I don't find much discussion on the topic. Though to be fair my search results could be hindered by many articles discussing stress and alcohol intake as opposed to stress and drinking liquids.